# Strange textures in render

Tags: texturing

I am currently making a movie on blender. One scene is a city scene, so, i duplicated buildings of the city to make the scene. But now, when i render the animation, i get this textures :[image]

Everything is rendered in Blender 2.78 and Cycles Render

As you can see, strange black squares appear and some faces of the building apper to be transparent. What could i do to solve this problem ?

[image]
This is the building's material.

I removed the precedent image, because i need more than 10 reputation to post more than 3 images.

Comment: Need more info, like screenshots of what the material for those parts look like in the node editor, and possibly a simplified version in file format to examine.

Comment: you seem to have a problem with lighting,as evident by the dark places.what are you using to light the scene.use a couple of sun lamps and adjust their position and strength and see if the dark shades disappear.

Comment: I do not think the screen shot you posted is of the correct material.

Comment: I have tested what KnowledgeSeeker said, but, the black squares are still there. What can i try ?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I am sorry, but the squares and light errors are still here. I put the lamp a syou said before but the image and lighting doesn't change.

Comment: OK try using a sky texture and increasing the strength.(in cycles go to world,surface(background),color(sky texture).).Also,looking at your node editor's screenshot it doesn't seem to be that of the building but of the green thing inside,maybe carpet or whatever it is.Usually on buildings we use diffuse shader and sometime maybe a combination of diffuse and a slight gloss or whatever depending on your custom demand.

Comment: I am really sorry.I have completed the task, but it didn't change

Comment: I noticed something new about the problem. In fact, it doesn't only affect the building on the image, but 2 others. Maybe the duplication could be source of this problem. I will now re-upload the image, because the screenshot of the Node Editor isn't of the correct material.